# PayPal Recurring & Single Payments in Canada (PayPal Payments Pro)

Tags: php, paypal, payment

we're looking at using PayPal Payments Pro (in Canada) to process membership fees (either monthly or annually) and also one off fees direct from our website.

Under our developer.paypal.com we can see Live API Credentials that states we can do subscriptions but it says "Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs [in Canada]" - is that what we would use to take credit card details direct on our website and process payments?

We were hoping to use the PayPal vault to store all the credit cards so we wouldn't have to ask the customer for them each time we do the single payments but it looks like that also isn't available in Canada.

Any clarification would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be considered off topic, and i'm sorry but I have to say it.

Use stripe.com, the API is well documented and simple to use.  I've been caught in pay-pal recurring payment hell before, and I'd just like to help you avoid it if possible.

Comment: I would love to use Stripe (or others) but it isn't possible for a few reasons. The 7-day rolling payout isn't ideal but the main reason is that from single payments we'll receive on the website we then need to send a certain amount of it on to other paypal accounts.